# Restriction of closed immersion to closed subset is a closed immersion

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a closed immersion in the category of algebraic sets. I think it's true that
for $Z \subseteq X$ closed the induced map $Z \to f(Z)$ is an isomorphism, i.e. the restriction to a closed subset is a closed immersion.
Unfortunately, I don't see how to prove that $f_{\ast}$ maps sections of $\mathcal{O}_{f(Z)}$ over some open subset $U$ of $f(Z)$ to sections of $\mathcal{O}_Z$ over $f^{-1}(U)$.
I know that $Z \hookrightarrow X \to Y$ is a morphism. Is there any helpful connection between the structure sheaf of $Y$ and the structure sheaf of $f(Z)$?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of closed immersion?

Comment: @Hoot $f(X)$ closed in $Y$ and $f$ defines an isomorphism between $X$ and its image.

Comment: Since the inclusion $\iota: Z\to X$ is a closed immersion, it induces a surjection $\mathcal{O}_{X,\iota(z)}\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{Z,z}$ for a point $z\in Z$. You furthermore know that $f$ induces a surjection $\mathcal O_{Y,f(z)}\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal O_{X,z}$ for any $z\in X$, in particular for $z=\iota(z)\in Z$. The composition of these two surjections is the local map induced by $f\circ\iota$, and it is a surjection as well. Does this answer the question?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Thanks for your comment. That would answer my question if I used a different definition. The definitions are probably equivalent, but I think it's harder to prove this equivalence than proving the statement I am after using the mentioned definition. Have you got any idea for that?

Comment: I think I have got it, I will write an answer if I got enough time for it.